# EnCase EnScript edit context menu

Tags: contextmenu

Is it possible to a add new item to the context menu (for example, to the Evidence window)? I have to write a script, which will create a new item in the context menu. This new item will run another script.

Comment: Please do some research on your behalf & ask here for specific problems.

Comment: You should describe clearly your problem in the question and try to put the code/effort which you have done